# Access referenced entity in Rules using hook_entity_property_info

Tags: rules, entities

I am using the Reply module for comment threads on a custom entity (we'll call it `myentity`). I'd like to create a rule that triggers when certain properties of `myentity` are met. However, the Reply module has very minimal `entity_property_info`, and so there's no way for rules to reference `myentity` in a condition.

The Reply module creates a Reply entity, that references an entity via entity_id column and an entity_type column. So, I created a `property_info_alter` hook as follows:

```
function mymodule_entity_property_info_alter(&$info) {
  $properties = &$info['reply']['properties'];

  $properties['entity_id'] = array(
    'label' => t("Entity id"), 
    'description' => t("The entity this reply is associated with."), 
    'type' => 'entity',
    'getter callback' => 'entity_property_verbatim_get',
    'required' => TRUE,
    'schema field' => 'entity_id',
  );
}
```

When I create a condition in rules of "Entity is of Type", I expect to find my new property as an option like `reply:entity-id` but it doesn't. It only appears in the condition "Data Comparison".

I feel like I'm missing something very simple, but really can't put my finger on it. How do I get this property to appear as a referenced entity that I can then evaluate in Rules?

Answer (score 0):

This works as-is. I actually had a typo in my code that took me a long time to catch. I'm leaving this up if anyone else has the same situation. The final code looked like this (cleaner):

```
function mymodule_entity_property_info_alter(&$info) {
  $properties = &$info['reply']['properties'];

  $properties['myentity'] = array(
    'label' => t("My Entity"), 
    'description' => t("The entity this reply is associated with."), 
    'type' => 'myentity',
    'required' => TRUE,
    'schema field' => 'entity_id',
  );
}
```